# Problem with Eszett while using Twig raw filter

Tags: twig

The following string contains html-tags:

```
<span>Schweißer</span>
```

For that reason i output that string as follows:

```
{{ myVariable | raw }}
```

I get the output "Schweisser" instead of "Schweißer".
Other like ö,ä,ü get displayed the right way but "ß" gets "ss", Why?

Note: I use UTF-8 and there is no problem with ö,ä,ü ...

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://twigfiddle.com/mi2ymj)